# xmlhttp.open() for external php file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have the line

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?id=4",true);
```

This does not work since file.php is not in the same folder but rather in a different private folder not visible to the public.

Is there a way to use the open function to open a file in a different folder?

Comment: If your AJAX request can access the script, other people can also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fundamentally impossible.

If you want to send an HTTP request to it, it must be visible to the public over HTTP.

Comment: If I move file.php in the same folder (public folder) can I make it so people can't type in the url to get to that file?

Comment: @SLaks Can you provide a code example using a one-time pad key?

Comment: @programm3r Technically no, but you could verify that the request coming in is sent through AJAX, and then finish or send back like a 404 if not AJAX. I'm pretty sure this could be faked, but at least it makes it harder

Comment: @ianpgall: The attacker can load the page, not execute the JS, then use the one-time key.

Comment: @SLaks I'm not sure what you mean. I was responding to the first comment by programm3r, to help distinguish between a normal and AJAX HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

You can only request files from within the public webspace. To access files outside the public webspace you need a script in the public webspace that can fetch the contents from the private folder, e.g.

```
<?php // file.php in the public webspace

    $allowedFiles = array(
        1 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file1.txt',
        2 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file2.txt',
        3 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file3.txt',
        4 => '/path/to/private/space/on/server/file4.txt',
    );

    $id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

    if (isset($allowedFiles[$id])) {
        readfile($allowedFiles[$id]);
    }
```

Now when you do

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.php?id=4",true);
```

the script will send the content of

```
/path/to/private/space/on/server/file4.txt
```

to the client.

#### Edit regarding some comments:

- Note that `readfile` will not execute the file contents. If you need to send the results of a PHP script, you have to use `include` instead of `readfile`. Please refer to the Manual for details.
- The above approach is effectively the same as most of the frameworks nowadays use. You have one single script that acts as a gateway into your application (kind of like a Front Controller pattern). This script accepts any and all requests (think mod_rewrite) to your application and is the only publicly accessible PHP file. It will bootstrap your application and then determine from the URL (or whatever you seem fit) what file, usually a controller when using MVC, in the private space should be instantiated and called.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: But this is no different from directly accessing it in a public place - this script would just be a middle man that adds unnecessary overhead. Sure, it's not directly accessible in the public root, but the user could still access the "private" file by accessing the script...and by accessing the script, I mean typing its URL in the browser and getting its result (which would be the private file)

Comment: @Gordon Would this code make it so that I could call an external PHP file using xmlhttp.open()?

Comment: @SLaks I put my comment above to see if Gordon is saying something different than you.

Comment: @programm3r what is an "external" file to you? the script above would act as a proxy file to an otherwise not publicly accessible file. there is no other way short of moving the private files into the public root.

Comment: @Gordon When I use the term "external" file I mean a file in a private folder outside the public webspace. Also, I tried using your code above, but my index.php file got automatically moved to the same private folder as the "external" file so that when I access index.php a list of folders and files is now displayed (not my home page anymore).

Comment: @programm3r there is nothing in the above code that would make your index.php get moved anywhere. All the script above does is to check whether there is a file path in the array for the id given in the URL. If so, it returns the file contents of that file.

Comment: @Gordon The code wasn't moving my index.php file. Somehow it got moved on its own, but I fixed that and ran your code again. My external php file's purpose is to establish a DB connection, execute a query, and send the query result back to the main file using json and populate textboxes based on the result. Before running your code the textboxes populated. After running your code they do not, so it seems like your code broke something.

Comment: @programm3r have you tried to understand what the code does instead of just copy and pasting it? it does a `readfile`. `readfile` wont execute the php code in your script. use `include` instead.

Comment: I made an assumption, apparently a wrong one, thinking your code worked. I have used the include function before. Are you saying you need to use the readfile function in combination with the include function or just the include function by itself?

Comment: @programm3r the code snippet above works as advertised and explained.

Comment: It may work as you see it in your mind, but others may not see it that same way. You used the word "fetch." If the php code is not being executed, then what does "fetch" really mean in your mind.

Comment: @programm3r My answer explicitly states the script will send/fetch the **content** [of file4.txt]. The txt extension hints at a text file and the example uses `readfile`. Whatever made you assume the example will execute some other script is just that: your assumption. Please try to understand the answer first before complaining that it doesn't work. Apart from that, yes, `include` will execute php code. Please refer to the PHP Manual on how to use it. Then adjust the example code so it works for your Use Case.

Comment: @Gordon I did not know that reading a file meant there is zero execution, so I assumed that the function readfile would work with a PHP file. Yes, I know this is my assumption, and I thought I understood what was happening. So don't accuse me of not trying to understand the answer. Also, using the word "complaining" to describe my response is a bit harsh. I tried replacing the word readfile with include and include_once but neither of them help with the population of the textboxes. Yes, I probably have the syntax wrong but no need to grill me about not trying/understanding.

Comment: @programm3r well, sorry about that then. It just came across like complaining to me. I cannot tell you why your textboxes don't get populated. I don't know your external script. It's definitely not an error in the example script above.

Comment: My main index page is located in the public webspace. My external file called loadTextBox.php is located in a private folder. The relevant code is provided via the following Pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/fDWcd4TH    Maybe there's something I need to do inside the external script as well?

Comment: @programm3r place `var_dump` calls throughout your script to see what happens or use a debugger, like XDebug, to step through the script to find where it goes wrong.

Comment: Since I have accepted an answer, I have removed the Pastebin link.